# Kudu Deployment Error : ENOENT

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, deployment, azure-devops, kudu

My application is based on VS2013 and I am using the Visual studio Team Services for continuous deployment.  Since I have API and Web project in the same solution the out of box feature does not work and it deploys only the api which is the first project in the solution.

I wanted to first test the default deploy.cmd file before going for customization as I found the customization was not getting recognized. I am trying to run the deploy.cmd from the VS2012 x64 Cross Tools command prompt. I generated this default deploy.cmd following the article. I am getting the error as below. I would see several articles on git hub but not much on VS Team Services. Can any one please provide some solution ?

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-hooks

**Error:**

> Kudu sync from: 'C:\Users\SYED\AppData\Local\Temp___deployTemp28127'
>   to: 'C
>   :\Users\syedsahabudeen\Source\Repos\Deployment..\artifacts\wwwroot'
>   Error: ENOENT, open
>   'C:\Users\syed\Source\Repos\Deployment\artifacts\manifest' Failed
>   exitCode=1, command="C:\Users\syed\AppData\Roaming\npm\kuduSync .cmd"
>   -v 50 -f "C:\Users\SYED\AppData\Local\Temp___deployTemp28127" -t "C:\ Users\syed\Source\Repos\Deployment..\artifacts\wwwroot" -n
>   "C:\Users\syed\Source\Repos\Deployment..\artifacts\manifest " -p
>   "C:\Users\syed\Source\Repos\Deployment..\artifacts\man ifest" -i
>   ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd" An error has occurred during web
>   site deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Kudu is not yet supported for GIT in Visual Studio Team Services.